# Reviewing first questions only shows one result

Tags: bug, estado-por-diseño

[image]

As you can see in the above image there is only one result when you are trying to review first questions and I'm pretty sure **Bird Jaguar IV** is not the only one with a first question in the site.

Is this a bug or I'm the only one with this problem?

Comment: That is strange... I see the same thing.

Comment: I see this too - we'll take a look.

Comment: +1 This also happens to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design but the UI does a pretty crappy job explaining the design.

If a post is reviewed by 2 members of the community it is dropped from the list. Will look at making the UI make more sense.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that :)